# Datatable : How to jump to the first empty cell

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using datatable to display predictions about future events. Among my columns I have "Day" "Hour" "Prediction" "Reality".

Prediction is always filled, but reality is only filled when the event happens.

I want to jump to the page corresponding to the current time. So I used jumpToData() on the date. With that, I have quick access to the last events of the current day but I still need to turn 4 or 5 pages if it's 9AM for example.

I think the easiest way to solve the problem is to jump to the first empty cell in the "Reality" column.

Have you any elements to do that ?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Thomas

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you were trying to achieve?:

```js
//Make up random chronological data to fill DataTable
var srcData = [...Array(300)].map((value, index) => {
  let obj = {};
  let today = new Date()
  let randomDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()-10, index);
  obj.date = randomDate.toLocaleDateString();
  obj.hour = index%24;
  obj.prediction = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
  obj.reality = randomDate < Date.now() ? obj.prediction+(3-Math.floor(Math.random()*6)) : '';
  return obj;
});
//Define DataTables object
var dataTable = $('#forecasts').DataTable({
  sDom: 'tp',
  orderFixed: [[0, 'asc'],[1, 'asc']],
  ordering: false,
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'date', data: 'date'},
    {title: 'hour', data: 'hour'},
    {title: 'prediction', data: 'prediction'},
    {title: 'reality', data: 'reality'},
  ]
});
$('#jumptoblank').on('click', () => {
  //Search for empty cell
  var emptyRowIndex = dataTable.rows().data().toArray().findIndex(row => row.reality == '');
  //Go to the page, where necessary row is located
  dataTable.page(Math.floor(emptyRowIndex/dataTable.page.info().length)).draw(false)
});
```

```css
.dataTables_wrapper {width: 600px}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="jumptoblank">Jump to blank reality</button>
    <table id="forecasts"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```